# c# - Issue with rounding of decimals when integral part is greater than 9 characters

Tags: c#, .net

In c#, conversion of double type number to string type with integral part having characters 9 or less gives correct values. But changing the integral part to have characters greater than 9, the results obtained are not as desired.

For example,

123456789.123456789 results "123456789.1235"(rounding to 4 decimals) which is correct.

But, 1234567891111.123456789, results "1234567891111.1200" is wrong.

Expected output is "1234567891111.1235".

Below is the code I have tried with two fixes but none of them are giving the desired output.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double sample = 0.0;
        string fieldText = "1234567891111.12345678";

    // Fix 1
    double.TryParse(fieldText,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out sample);
    Console.WriteLine(sample); // 1234567891111.12

    // Fix 2
    string FormattedText = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0.0000}", 1234567891111.123446789);
    Console.WriteLine(FormattedText); // 1234567891111.1200

    // Expected output - 1234567891111.1235

    }
}
```

Please suggest,

1. How to get correct rounding of decimals with integral part having more characters (>9) as stated in the example ?
2. Also, how to display the complete number(1234567891111.123456789) instead scientific notation(1.23456789111112E+21) while converting Double type to string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such thing as "correct" rounding.  There are different types of rounding, and I suggest you read up on the topic, specifically which type .NET uses.

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: On top of what Caius Jard said, which is correct, floating point does not have exact representations for all values, in fact there's an infinite amount of "non-integer" values that cannot be represented as an exact value in floating point.

Comment: `string FormattedText = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:E12}", 1234567891111.123446789M);` may be worth a try.

Comment: `var rounded = Math.Round(1234567891111.123446789, 4); string formattedText = rounded.ToString("R4");` Or `string formattedText = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:R4}", 1234567891111.123446789);`

Answer (score 2):

The type `double` can only store floating point numbers to a certain precision (about 15 significant figures). The number 1234567891111.12345678 is too precise to be stored in a `double`. `double` can only store something as precise as 1234567891111.12.

One way to fix this is to use a type that is even more precise than `double`: `decimal`.

By adding an `m` to the end of the literal, the literal becomes a `decimal` literal:

```
string FormattedText = string.Format(
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    "{0:0.0000}", 
    1234567891111.123446789m);
Console.WriteLine(FormattedText);
```

Obviously, `decimal` can only go to a certain precision as well.

Answer (score 0):

> But, 1234567891111.123456789, results "1234567891111.1200" is wrong.
>   Expected output is "1234567891111.1235".

Yes, but a double can't store that many digits. [The Fine Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) says that double is good for about 15 digits, and 1234567891111.12 is 15 digits.. After that you trying to make a double like this:

```
double d = 1234567891111.1234
```

Results in your double actually only tracking this:

```
double d = 1234567891111.12;
```

So when you format it with 4 decimal places, it'll print `1234567891111.1200`

This isn't about the size (magnitude) of the number in the double, it's about the number of digits. Trying to store `1.000 0000 0000 0000 0001` (20 digits) in a double just plain up won't work out and that double will be `1`

Answer (score 0):

The type `double` does not have enough space to store that many digits. Use the type [`Decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal) instead.

```
Decimal sample = 0.0M;
string fieldText = "1234567891111.12345678";

Decimal.TryParse(fieldText, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out sample);

string FormattedText = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:0.0000}", sample);
Console.WriteLine(FormattedText);
```